# How do you check that a trained vocab and TfidfVectorizer is applied correctly to another corpus?

Tags: python, nlp, tfidfvectorizer

I am trying to train an NLP model on one set, save the vocab and the model, then apply it to a separate validation set. The code is running, but how can I be sure it is working as I expect?

In other words, I have saved a vocab and nmodel from the training set, then I created the TFidfVectorizer with saved vocabulary, and finally I use "fit_transform" on the new, validation notes.

Is this applying only the trained vocab and model? Is it not "learning" anything new from the validation set?

Training, then load the vocab and model and apply to the validation set:

````
train_vector = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(training_notes)
pickle.dump(tfidf_vectorizer.vocabulary_, open('./vocab/' + '_vocab.pkl', 'wb'))
X_train = train_vector.toarray()
y_train = np.array(train_data['ref_std'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
dump(model, './model/' + '.joblib')
train_prediction = model.predict(X_train)


vocab = pickle.load(open('./vocab/' + '_vocab.pkl', 'rb'))
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(vocabulary = vocab)    
valid_vector = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(validation_notes)
X_valid = valid_vector.toarray()
y_valid = np.array(validation_data['ref_std'])
model = load('./model/' + '.joblib')
valid_prediction = model.predict(X_valid)```
````

Comment: The way you've described it, it absolutely _IS_ learning from the new validation set, and in fact you're telling it to disregard the learned vocab and weights from the training set. Rather than using `fit_transform` on the validation data, you should only be using `.transform()`, since the `fit_` step retrains the model

Answer (score 1):

Answering your questions:

> Is this applying only the trained vocab and model?

As stated by @G. Anderson as a comment to your answer, when you call "fit", you are refitting the Tf-idf dict to your new data - this implies giving new weights to words (I assume you know what is [TF-IDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf)). Therefore, to be able to use the trained vocab, use only:

```
vocab = pickle.load(open('./vocab/' + '_vocab.pkl', 'rb'))
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(vocabulary = vocab)    
valid_vector = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(validation_notes)
```

Assuming that you apply the above mentioned corrections, the second question can be answered:

> Is it not "learning" anything new from the validation set?

No, you're just **validating** it. You use the same tf-idf vectorization because you want to fit the new entries based on your original data - to that, you have a custom set of weights depicting the words your model values the most. If you keep changing your tf-idf dict, you'll have different weights (they can average out if you consider lots of data, but I assume that this is not te fact).

So, once you have a model and a tf-idf calculation, everything is fixed, nothing more is learnt except if you log data to further enchance the model.